# Stone space of measure algebra

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebras, lebesgue-measure

let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on the unit interval $I=[0,1]$, and $Leb(I)$ be the Boolean algebra of Lebesgue measurable in $I$ and $\mathcal{N}$ the family of Null sets. The measure algebra $\mathcal{M}$ can be identified with the quotient algebra modulo Null sets, which is the set of equivalence classes that determined by the equivalence relation  $\sim$, i.e. :

$$ \text{If } A,B\in Leb(I), \text{then  } A\sim B\text{ iff } A\Delta B\in \mathcal{N}$$

By $[A]$ I denote an element in $\mathcal{M}$, so $[A]=\{B\in Leb(I): A\sim B\}$.

Such classes have these properties:

(1) If $A\in [B]$, then $[A]=[B]$,

(2) Every two classes either have empty or nonempty intersection. 
So if $[A]\cap[B]\neq\emptyset$, there $C\in[A]\cap[B]$ implies that $[C]=[A\cap B]=[A]=[B]$.

(3) If $[A]\subseteq [B]\implies [A]=[B]$.

Let $Y=St(\mathcal{M})$, Stone space, is the set of all ultrafilter on $\mathcal{M}$.

> Q1\ I am asking how to make ultrafilters by these equivalence classes which have the above properties (i.e. we do not proper intersection and supersetness).
>
> Q2\ (Just added) How to construct the Stone space of $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "make ultrafilters by these equivalence classes"? Does it help to observe that ultrafilters in the measure algebra correspond to ultrafilters $U$ in the algebra of measurable sets such that all sets of measure $1$ are elements of $U$?

Comment: Define ordering: $[A] \le [B]$ iff $B \setminus A \in \mathcal N$.  Define "intersection" $[A] \wedge [B] = [A \cap B]$.  And so on.

Comment: @AndreasBlass What I meant was, the point in $Y$ are ultrafilters on the measure algebra $\mathcal{M}$ (element in $\mathcal{M}$ are equivalence classes). My question how to make unltrafilters on $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Why ? Please give more details. What is the benefit of defining that ordering.

Comment: What is the definition of "ultrafilter" on a Boolean algebra?  Does it have to do with the ordering on the Boolean algebra, and the intersection relation on it?  Or what?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, Yes, I know what do you indicate to. But what is the difference between the inclusion $\subseteq$ and $\leq$ on those classes, (as I know) they are doing the same job (as I considered $\mathcal{M}$ to be an algebra).

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks alot ...Please read the comment I wrote it under your answer.

Comment: If the problem was merely to explain what the measure algebra is, then Gerald Edgar has answered it and it isn't really a research-level question.  If the problem was something else, then the question should be clarified. Either way, I'll vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

On the collection $\mathcal M$ of equivalence classes, define ordering:
$$
[A] \le [B] \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad B\setminus A \in \mathcal N
$$
Of course, this is **not** the same as $A \subseteq B$.  Nor is it the same as $[A] \subseteq [B]$.

Define "intersection" by
$$
[A] \wedge [B] = [A \cap B]
$$
And (as you noted in your question) this is not the same as $[A] \cap [B]$.  Define "union" as
$$
[A] \vee [B] = [A \cup B]
$$
Define "complement" as
$$
[A]' = [I \setminus A]
$$
Of course this is not the complement $Leb(I) \setminus [A]$.
Define the "zero element" by
$$
\mathbf{o} = [\varnothing]
$$
Then $\mathbf{o} \ne \varnothing$.  In fact $\mathbf{o} = \mathcal N$, but that is probably not a helpful way to think of it.

Define the "unit element" by
$$
\mathbf{e} = [I]
$$

With the operations $\le, \vee, \wedge, {}', \mathbf{o}, \mathbf{e}$, we make $\mathcal M$ into a Boolean algebra. (Check this!) The ultrafilters you want are ultrafilters in that Boolean algebra.